# How to change lsync log level or completely disable it?

Tags: centos, lsyncd

I'm using lsync for incremental backup. After 6 month it generated about 6GB log file in `/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log`.

I decide to change log level to reduce log generation. there is an option '-log' in [lsync man file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/lsyncd.1.html) and there is a config file in 'nano /etc/lsyncd.lua'.

I want know how set '-log' option in 'lsyncd.lua' file to disable or change log level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with lsyncd, but judging from the man file `-log scarce` should be added to the start-up script `/etc/init.d/lsyncd`

```
daemon $lsyncd -log scarce -pidfile $pidfile $config
```

I would also recommend adding `/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log` to logrotate.

Create `/etc/logrotate.d/lsyncd` with following:

```
/var/log/lsyncd/*log {
missingok
notifempty
sharedscripts
postrotate

/sbin/service lsyncd restart > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true

endscript
}
```