# lsyncd dumping every file transferred to log

Tags: lsyncd

I have lsyncd configured thus:

```
settings {
        logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
        statusFile = "/tmp/lsyncd.stat",
        statusInterval = 1,
        verbose = false,
}

sync {
        default.rsync,
        source    = '/xxxx/',
        target      = 'host:/xxxx/',
        delay     = 1,
}
```

When I invoke it as `lsyncd -log Exec /etc/lsyncd/homedirs.lua` the log file becomes extremely large extremely quickly, as every single file transferred is dumped to the log. How can I disable this? It's extremely bad design for something to be this verbose by default.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-log scarce' as suggested in the answer to https://serverfault.com/questions/682176/how-to-change-lsync-log-level-or-completely-disable-it

Comment: That pretty much removes EVERYTHING except actual errors. I'd like to have basic status (initial sync completed, etc.) without having every single file being transferred logged as well.